# Add new empty row to dataGridView bound to DataSet

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am not handy at this. I have a dataGridView bound to SQL by a dataset. All column are generated by the dataset except one column which is replaced by a coded one which is a comboboxColumn. 
To avoid new columns being generated while editing a row, I have set the allowUserToAddRows to false. Now I would like to add new empty rows by button click. I have tried in several way without any success.
**Updated with full code**

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.affitto_saTableAdapter.Fill(this.affitto_SADataSet.affitto_sa);
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        comboCol1.Name = "Periodo Rif.";
        List<DateTime> periods = new List<DateTime>() { DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2), DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2) };
        //Dates = Dates.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        List<string> colSource = periods.Select(x => x.ToString("MMM/yyyy")).ToList();
        comboCol1.DataSource = colSource;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboCol1);
        comboCol1.DataPropertyName = "Periodo";
        dataGridView1.Columns["Periodo Rif."].DisplayIndex = 1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       /* DataTable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(row);*/

        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).Rows.Add((dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).NewRow());

    }
}
```

How can I add a new empty row to such DGV?

Comment: This code should work. Can you please explain what went wrong? PS: bear in mind that a blank row for a combobox column means a combobox (with -1 as selectedindex, that is, no item selected).

Comment: @varocarbas, with the above code I get a null reference exception and I do not understand why.

Comment: I have tried your code (by adding a proper datasource to the DataGridView, what is not present in what you posted) and everything is fine. Can you please include the part where you set the DataSource?

Comment: @varocarbasI updated the question with the full code I have in this app.

Comment: `as DataTable` expects a `DataTable` as `DataSource`, if this is not the case you are casting to the wrong type. Perhaps you prefer to set the `DataSource` at runtime (with a `DataTable`). Don't populate anything from the design view, create a `DataTable` (`dt`) variable and populate it from the source you want (a DB, I understand), write `DataGridView1.DataSource = dt` and your code would work.

Comment: You are welcome. I do prefer doing most of things at runtime, mainly with datasources (it avoid this kind of "synchronisation problems").

Answer (score 1):

Here solution for your problem:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.AddCopy(myDataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1);
```

Since your DGV not binded with any of dataSource hence `AddCopy` of `DataGridViewRow` will add new row at end of DGV (at `Rows.Count - 1`).

Comment: I get a null reference exception, I do not get why!

Comment: @FeliceM If DGV have dataSource binded then it is imposible! Check if DGV has dataSource as DataTable or not

Comment: As I said am not really handy at this. I have updated the question with all the code I have in the form.

Comment: @FeliceM I think here DGV not binded with any of DataSource, in such case edited answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

    }
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers - add some explanation to the snipes.

Comment: Additionally, in the context of this question, this answer does not work.  You will recieve the following exception: _"Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."_